# Need help with dynamic image grid

Tags: assets, entry, structure, bootstrap-craft

I am trying to make my image grid form out dynamically. I got it kinda working, But I need to figure out how to make my grid rows dynamic. I am kinda forcing it to start a new row at every 4th item right now, but dossent feel like the right way to do it.

This is my code:

```
    <div class="widewrapper weak-highlight"> <!-- knappebilde start -->

    <div class="container content col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
 {% for entry in craft.entries.section('knapperForside').limit(50).find() %}        
            <div class="showroom-item col-md-3">
                <div class="image">
                    {{ entry.bilde }}
                    <!-- overlay start -->
                    <a class="overlay" href="{{ entry.knappUrl }}">
                         <i class="glyphicons search"></i>
                         <div class="name">{{ entry.title }}</div>
                    </a>
                    <!-- overlay stop -->
                </div>  <!-- Image Stop -->
                <a href="{{ entry.title }}"><h4>{{ entry.title }}</h4></a>
            </div>
  {% endfor %}           
         </div>      <!--  row stop  -->
    </div>          <!-- Container Stop -->        

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>     <!-- knappebilde stop -->
```

Comment: What is the desired result? Got any more details? Or possibly a screenshot of how it currently looks and what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 1):

To add a row at every 4th item, you can use twig's batch filter:

[Twig Batch](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/batch.html)

Alternatively(a little more hacky) you can do `{% if loop.index is divisible by(4) %} stuff {% endif %}`. But batch is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replys! after doing some reading on bootstrap docs, it seems it was somewhat the right way to do it. But I had to do some changes in the way I refered to the images